# React js Validation textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am trying to make a validation in reactjs.
For example, I have a field called "name" and every time you input a name, this has to be bigger or equal to 2. It works when the name is smaller than 2, but if it's bigger than 2 the message still appears.
Here is my code:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
nameValid: true,
prenumeValid: true,
check_textInputChange: false,
name: "",
});

const handleValidUser = (val) => {
if (val.length >= 2) {
  setData({
    ...data,
    nameValid: true,
  });
} else {
  setData({
    ...data,
    nameValid: false,
    });
    }
  };
  const textInputChange = (val) => {
  if (val.length >= 2) {
    setData({
    ...data,
    name: val,
    nameValid: true,
    check_textInputChange: true,
  });
} else {
  setData({
    ...data,
    name: val,
    nameValid: false,
    check_textInputChange: false,
  });
}
 };


 <TextField
      type="text"
      variant="outlined"
      label="Nume"
      required
      fullWidth
      autofocus
      validate
      style={{ marginBottom: "1em" }}
      onChange={(val) => textInputChange(val)}
      onBlur={(e) => handleValidUser(e)}
    />
    {data.nameValid ? null : (
      <text>The name has to be at least 2 letters long</text>
    )}
```

Comment: Next time, I suggest you fix your indentation before post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**onChange** has an **event** parameter, if you want to get the value of the **TextField**, you should write it as below.

```js
const textInputChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    
    if (val.length > 2) {
        setData(...)
    } else {
        setData(...)
    }
}

return (
    <TextField
        ...
        onChange={textInputChange}
        onBlur={handleValidUser} // as well as onBlur
    />
)
```

I've created a codesandbox to demonstrate [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-rubin-j7m1m?file=/src/App.js).

Call the function as below will create an extra render every time the function is called. You should avoid it.

```js
onChange={(val) => textInputChange(val)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing

```
onChange={(val) => textInputChange(val)}
```

to this:

```
onChange={(e) => textInputChange(e.target.value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

in function **textInputChange** you are passing event object instead of input value
you have to change **onchange** handler from:

```
onChange={(val) => textInputChange(val)}
```

to

```
onChange={(val) => textInputChange(val.target.value)}
```